# Get ord() values from single-character columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization, ord

With a dataframe like this:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['x', 'y', 'z'],
])
```

We can get the `ord()` mapping for each character:

```py
>>> ordinals = df.apply(lambda x: [ord(c) for c in x])

>>> ordinals
     0    1    2
0   97   98   99
1  100  101  102
2  120  121  122
```

Is it possible to get the same result in a vectorised manner, so that we avoid using `apply` on each row which is extremely slow with 1.5M+ rows?

Answer (score 1):

Use `applymap`:

```
df.applymap(ord)
```

Ex:

```
>>> df.applymap(ord)
     0    1    2
0   97   98   99
1  100  101  102
2  120  121  122
>>>
```

Or with `np.vectorize` (might be quicker, since it's numpy):

```
>>> df[:] = np.vectorize(ord)(df)
>>> df
     0    1    2
0   97   98   99
1  100  101  102
2  120  121  122
>>>
```

Comment: I think you're enjoying the fact that @jezrael is not around :p